# My array Printing NULL

Tags: java, arrays, null

In the method, i have all these initialize

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = new File("order.dat");
    File viewOrder = new File("ViewOrder.dat");

    String orderNo, itemNo, itemNameHolder, qtyHolder, priceHolder, status;
    int hold, count = 0, countArray = 0;
    double tempPriceHolder, totalPrice = 0;
    String tempStatus = "";

    String[] holdItemNo = null;
    String[] holdName = null;
    Integer[] holdQty = null;
    Double[] holdTotal = null;
    String[] holdStatus = null;
```

After, i try to read all my content in the file and store the content into holdX array

```
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String tokens[] = line.split(";");

            orderNo = tokens[0];
            itemNo = tokens[1];
            itemNameHolder = tokens[2];
            qtyHolder = tokens[3];
            priceHolder = tokens[4];
            status = tokens[5];

            if (orderNo.equalsIgnoreCase(userOrderNo)) {

                tempPriceHolder = Double.parseDouble(priceHolder);
                hold = Integer.parseInt(qtyHolder);
                tempPriceHolder = tempPriceHolder * hold;
                totalPrice += tempPriceHolder;

                countArray++;
                holdItemNo = new String[countArray];
                holdName = new String[countArray];
                holdQty = new Integer[countArray];
                holdTotal = new Double[countArray];
                holdStatus = new String[countArray];                

                if (status.matches("s")) {

                    tempStatus = "Success";
                } else if (status.matches("p")) {
                    tempStatus = "Partially Full";
                } else if (status.matches("o")) {
                    tempStatus = "Out of Stock";
                }

                holdItemNo[count] = itemNo;
                holdName[count] = itemNameHolder;
                holdQty[count] = hold;
                holdTotal[count] = tempPriceHolder;
                holdStatus[count] = tempStatus;

                count++;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
```

Final, i write all my array into a new file.

```
        System.out.printf("%s %15s %15s %10s %10s\n", "Item No", "Description", "Quantity", "Total", "Status");

    for (int i = 0; i < holdItemNo.length; i++) {            
        System.out.printf("\n%-11s %-18s %-13s $%-8s %s \n", holdItemNo[i], holdName[i], holdQty[i], holdTotal[i], holdStatus[i]);           
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.printf("%46s %s\n", "$", totalPrice);

    System.out.print("Print Order to file Y/N: ");
    String choice = input.next();

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        try {
            PrintWriter bw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("ViewOrder.dat", true));

            for (int i = 0; i < holdItemNo.length; i++) {
                bw.write(userOrderNo + ";" + holdItemNo[i] + ";" + holdName[i] + ";" + holdQty[i] + ";" + holdTotal[i] + ";" + holdStatus[i] + "\n");
                bw.flush();
            }

            bw.flush();
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Sucessfull!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {

        System.out.println("");
    }
```

but the problem is even my code is working but the output is not what i expected. It printed out the printed out the last content and also the sub price is working as well but the rest is only printed out NULL.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk22S.png)

Also, it gave me warning of Derefencing possible null pointer on the array.length

```
for (int i = 0; i < holdItemNo.length; i++) {
                bw.write(userOrderNo + ";" + holdItemNo[i] + ";" + holdName[i] + ";" + holdQty[i] + ";" + holdTotal[i] + ";" + holdStatus[i] + "\n");
                bw.flush();
           }
```

Comment: Time to fire up the old debugger to actually see for yourself why things are not behaving as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing:

```
holdItemNo = new String[countArray];
```

and the following lines: you are creating these **new** array objects **within** your reading loop (inside a condition).

So probably that condition never goes true; therefore your arrays stay all null. But even when the condition is met - you probably expect that to happen **more** then once. And guess what: you are creating completely **new** arrays then. While **throwing away** the previously created array. Each time the if condition turns true you will lose previously stored values!

So the answer is: create your arrays **before** entering the loop. This means that you either have to query "how many slots to create" upfront; or you have to create an array with say 100 empty slots; and within your loop you then have to check if you still have free slots.

Or you start using java.util.List resp. ArrayList - which allows for dynamic adding of elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!! Still trying to find a way to eliminate the remaining slot after i create several of them.

Comment: After the loop is done find out how many slots are taken. Create new arrays of that smaller size and then copy over the data slot.

Comment: Okay, so i decided to add these code after whileLoop                                 '            for (int i = 0; i < holdItemNo.length; i++) {

                if (!(holdItemNo[i].equals("null"))) {
                    countNum++;

                }
            }

            storeItemNo = new String[countNum];

            for (int i = 0; i < storeItemNo.length; i++) {

                storeItemNo[i] = holdItemNo[i];
                System.out.println(storeItemNo[i]);

            }
' but it stop doing their "thing" after forLoop and jump to print out section..